# Displaying byte array as image; base64 data URI doesn't work above 32KB in IE

Tags: image, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a image as `byte[]` in my bean. User can upload image using `<h:inputFile/>`. As soon as user clicks upload the image should be displayed in the page(Should not be saved in DB/Folder). I tried using Base64 convertion but in IE it's displaying only 32KB size image.
Below is my xhtml code.
`<h:form id="signatureform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <h:inputFile id="inputFile" label="file1"  value="#{bean.part}"/>
       <h:commandButton id="upButton" type="submit"
                    action="#{bean.uploadSignature}"
                    value="Upload" styleClass="commandButton">
        </h:commandButton>
</h:form>`
`<h:graphicImage url="data:image/jpg;base64,#{bean.encodedImage}" 
                                    width="275px" height="75px"></h:graphicImage>`
My Java code is

```
private String encodedImage ;
private Part part;
//getters and setters 
public String uploadSignature() throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = part.getInputStream();
        encodedImage = new String(Base64.encode(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)));
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

I have tried with `<a4j:mediaOutput/>` but no help. Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: Why would you *not* be saving it somewhere? Surely that's the point of them uploading it.

Comment: Yeah correct. There is another Save button on cicking of Save it will be saved to DB. Save is working fine, only issue is displaying.

Comment: So save it to the database *immediately*, but with a flag to say it's unconfirmed - or save it in a different table, perhaps. Aside from anything else, that means when the user *does* click Save, you've already got the data... *and* it means you can display it trivially.

Comment: But the issue is if the user close the browser image will be saved in the DB where it should not be. Other than image we hane many fields where user will enter data and save. If the don't want to save the data  the then we need to discard everything.

Comment: Sure, so you effectively garbage collect - keep a timestamp when the user first uploaded the image, and then purge it after an hour or something like that. Keeping the data when they first upload it will make your life a *lot* simpler overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finall i was able to display my Image in IE. My requirement was to display an image in 275px *75px. For this requirement i resized my image in Java and displayed in the Web page. When i resized my image and converted to Base64 string it became less than 32kb. I tried with 12MB image and it worked fine :). Below is my code.

```
        BufferedImage imBuff = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
        BufferedImage resizedImg = resize(imBuff, 275, 75);
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(resizedImg, "jpg", os);
        encodedImage = new String(Base64.encode(os.toByteArray()));
```

```
private  BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage image, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        int currentWidth = image.getWidth();
        int currentHeight = image.getHeight();
        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, image.getType());
        Graphics2D graphics2d = newImage.createGraphics();
        graphics2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        graphics2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, 0, 0,
                currentWidth, currentHeight, null);
        graphics2d.dispose();
        return newImage;
    }
```

Hope this will help others who are trying to display a big image in small size in the web page.

Comment: So i have a question that, do you try upload it from Chrome then save it and load it from IE? because in my case I can upload from Chrome and load it from IE but cannot upload it from IE

Comment: @Shen I guess I tried like uploading it from IE and showing it in IE. It's been more than 2 years I worked on that project. Are you getting any error? If no error then try with small size image (less than 32 KB).